# Dockerize ESLint with presets

Tags: docker, npm, gitlab, eslint, vue-cli

I'm trying to create a GitLab CI/CD stage that would only lint my code and run before all other steps. The trouble is that I'm trying to have the linting (together with its configuration) on a pre-built image for speed optimization reasons.

My `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
stages:
  - prelint
  - lint
  - build
  - deploy

build-linter:
  stage: prelint
  script: echo 'This builds the linter image'
  only:
    changes:
      - Dockerfile.lint

lint:
  stage: lint
  image: prebuilt-linter
  script:
    - npm run lint
```

And the contents of `Dockerfile.lint`:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

RUN npm i -g eslint \
  prettier \
  @babel/core \
  core-js \
  core-js-compat@3.4.7 \
  eslint-config-prettier \
  eslint-plugin-prettier \
  eslint-plugin-vue \
  @vue/cli-service \
  @vue/cli-plugin-eslint \
  @vue/cli-plugin-babel \
  @vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest \
  @vue/cli-plugin-e2e-nightwatch \
  @vue/eslint-config-prettier \
  babel-eslint

WORKDIR /app
CMD eslint
```

However, it currently errors out because I think it's trying to find the dependencies from the project's own `node_modules/` directory and won't use the globally installed ones.

```
$ npm run lint
00:01
> @project/1.0.0 lint /builds/frontend
> vue-cli-service lint
 ERROR  Error: Cannot find module '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset' from '/builds/frontend'
Error: Cannot find module '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset' from '/builds/frontend'
    at Function.resolveSync [as sync] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/resolve/lib/sync.js:81:15)
    at resolveStandardizedName (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:101:31)
    at resolvePreset (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:58:10)
    at loadPreset (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:77:20)
    at createDescriptor (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:154:9)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:50
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at createDescriptors (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:109:29)
    at createPresetDescriptors (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:101:10)
    at presets (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:47:19)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @project@1.0.0 lint: `vue-cli-service lint`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @project@1.0.0 lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-04-14T18_59_23_427Z-debug.log
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

What would be the best approach to have the dependencies necessary to make `eslint` work available in the built image, without having to install the dependencies each time? I wouldn't want to rely on installing the `devDependencies` of the project since there'd still be cache busts quite often because of irrelevant dependencies getting patched etc.

Comment: What if you add `@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset` dependency as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68101438/1555615) but with `-g`?